# Timeline server application logs pointing to 0.0.0.0

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, timeline, resourcemanager

I have setup timeline server on my Hadoop 2.7.

Enabled timeline server on http port 8188

It is working fine, able to view all jobs on UI.

Now whenever I check application attempt logs, container logs  (link) 
It points to

```
0.0.0.0:8188/applicationhistory/logs/host:port/container...
```

Now I want it to point to correct host and logs directory.

I have enabled below properties in yarn-site.xml - Yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true and Yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir=

Comment: Are you running on a multi-node cluster?

Comment: No. I’m running on single node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mapr 6.1 , there is hidden property 
Yarn.timeline-service.webapp.all-ifaces =false

It should work
Validated and tested.